# Failed to click and navigate to next page for certain website-VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I want to navigate and choose menu bar from [this](http://fisis.fss.or.kr/fss/fsiview/indexw.html) website. For your information, I was able to get the selected ID of the element but don't have any clue on how to make the page is success when clicking the menu. I am using IE11 and macros to makes things work. Here is my code:

```
Dim IEap As InternetExplorer,htmldoc, el as variant
Set IEap= New InternetExplorer
IEap.navigate("http://fisis.fss.or.kr/fss/fsiview/indexw.html"): IEap.visible= True: DoEvents: Sleep 6000 '''navigate URL
Set htmldoc= IEap.document
For each el in htmldoc.getelementsbytagname("div")
    If ee.ID = "mainframe_ChildFrame0_form_div_submenu00_div_submenu_menu_02_menu02_04TextBoxElement" Then '''want to click "금융통계정보" to navigate next page
    ee.Focus: ee.Click '''im trying this- Failed
    ee.FireEvent ("onclick") ''''this also -Failed
next el
```

Is there any special method other than this? Could you please share your suggestion if you don't mind? As this is my first time facing the complicated website like this. Thanks for your help :)
P\S: Avoid to using GUI or API method. Thx

Comment: Are you going to scrape some data from the website finally?

Comment: Yup...but in some reason, I need to click the menu as the data will change every month. Due to that, I have no choice unless come out with dynamic code to always cater the latest data(after clicking the menu, you will find the list of data)..I just want this figure so that I can extract the information...

Comment: Have you tried an [API](http://efisis.fss.or.kr/fss/fsi/id/fssOpenAPIView40_en.jsp)?

Comment: @omegastripes As per my question as above, I want to avoid API as it will high possibilities the key will changes every month. I really want to get the information based on the direction that I had informed previously. The reason I don't want to use GUI as it will using sendkey function which will limited the movement of user when running the macro. I also want to avoid this as well. Is there any way to click the menu so that I can navigate to the next page? Thx.